# ASP.NET and Identity 2.0 roles with VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to build webpage with Microsoft Passport authentication. That works fine but how to use roles for authenticated users?

I have problems to understand how roles is working with 2.0.

I am able to create new role with `Roles.CreateRole("TestRole")` but if I have understand right it using Identity 1.0? at least it creates record to Roles table in database not AspNetRoles.

I think that I need to use `RoleManager` and `UserManager`?

Any examples how to do that with VB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For creating role use `RoleManager` and for assigning role to user Use `UserManager`.

```
RoleManager = New RoleManager(Of IdentityRole)(New RoleStore(Of IdentityRole)(New MyDbContext()))
Dim roleresult = RoleManager.Create(New IdentityRole(roleName))

UserManager.AddToRole(currentUser.Id, roleName)
```

Comment: it says myDbContext is not defined. I have imported Microsoft.AspNet.Identity and Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework. Do I need something else ?

Comment: replace myDbContext with your own IdentityDbContext

Comment: Wow. Everyday something new :) Got that work with this. Dim RoleManager = New RoleManager(Of IdentityRole)(New RoleStore(Of IdentityRole)(New ApplicationDbContext()))
        'Dim roleresult = RoleManager.Create(New IdentityRole("Administrator"))

Comment: OK. That was too soon. I was able to create role but not add user to that. I used  'Dim UserManager = New UserManager(Of IdentityUser)(New UserStore(Of IdentityUser)(New ApplicationDbContext())) Dim UserResult = UserManager.AddToRole(userID, rolename)'. But getting error "The entity type IdentityUser is not part of the model for the current context."